# Normalize scores by frequency

Tags: math, statistics

Consider we have 2 games/movie having

Game 1: Rated 90 by 10,000 users

Game 2: Rated 92 by 1,200 users

Users can rate from min: 1 to max: 100 on their scale meter

What is the best way to normalize these scores so that we take into account the number of users who has voted it

Answer (score 1):

Weighted average:

```
WeightedRating = (Rating1 * Count1 + Rating2 * Count2) / (Count1 + Count2)
```

In general

```
WeightedRating = Sum(Rating[i] * Count[i]) / Sum(Count[i])
```